# Android activity background does not been transparent when I use SwipeBackLayout and swipe it below api 21

Tags: android, swipe, swipe-gesture

I'm developing my app with SwipeBackLayout and my Activity is extends from SwipeBackActivity.The foreground activity's background is transparent when I swipe back in my devices with android api 21.But it does not work in device with api 19.

Like this:
this is the picture in device api 19

[image]

this is the picture in device api 21

[image]

and below is my style.xml in values-v19:

```
<!-- in values-v19 -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme2" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
<style name="WelcomeTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and this is my style.xml in values-v21

```
<!-- in values-v21 -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme2" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>

<style name="WelcomeTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

in manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".manager.MyApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >
.........
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

ah, I got it. because of the code below in my activity:

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
```

so the background of my Activity is not transparent.

Comment: delete it and everything will be ok